# How do you properly use a .desktop icon to launch a python3.8 Tkinter GUI on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, ubuntu-18.04

Premise: I coded a Tkinter GUI for a python script. It works. I can launch it from terminal. I created an icon and the icon will show up in my GUI just fine. I've been looking for tutorial on .desktop launchers and none of the examples I've found work. After a few hours of wading through SEO spam in SERPs trying to find a tutorial on the subject or a forum question that has been correctly answered. Finally I decided to join a forum ask a question. I've found a lot of code snippets on this site in the past. Figured I would try here.

I've tried about 20 different examples none of which have worked but I think I at least know the questions to ask. Here's an example of a .desktop file: It's not an example that works but it's one on found on this site so I figure I will start there.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/path/to/icon/icon.ico
Name=ApplicationName
Exec=python3 /path/to/application.py
Categories=Application;
```

Note the example in the other post shows a red highlight over Categories=Utility; and when I try to change it in /usr/share/applications/ it makes gnome-terminal insert an A when hit the up key to get my last BASH entry and change a bunch of keys on my keyboard into hotkeys rather than being able to type it pops open print dialogs and things like that that which is wicked annoying.

Does anyone want to discuss what each entry line in a .desktop file is supposed to look like. Also does the application, icon, and everything have to be in /usr/share/applications? What file locations are ok to use in this type of file?

Something else I thought of; is it possible that my Exec line is not correct. Does exec have to be a single argument? Do I need to create a bash script that can be called by Exec that is just something like ./script.sh or should I create a command alias that is a single argument? Or does it actually matter?

I also have a Linux question: What package handles .desktop icons? Who maintains said package? And where can I find actual documentation on the subject?

Comment: Better give the full path of `python3` in `Exec` option and also set `Path` option as well.  Document on the [.desktop](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html).

Comment: So I changed the .desktop file and I ran into another problem. The old one won't delete. The old icon is still on the desktop interface and the launcher is still broken. Deleted the file move a copy of the new one to the correct location. They must be cached somewhere.